# Img src tag is working when I pass the actual URL but when I pass constant instesd of URL it does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

It's just a simple program to show weather data on HTML page with the help of open weather API. I am trying to store image URL in imgurl variable and pass it in img tag. But I am not able to get the Image. BUT when I paste actual image URL in img tag it works. I have tested the Image URL by console.log of the constant imgurl and found it correct. I want to pass the imgurl variable in img tag to get the image.

```
const express = require('express');

const https = require('https');

const app = express();


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
 
    const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=e3b069cb4447ba5b054a354f9ed3f6ba&units=metric";

    https.get(url, function (responce) {

        console.log(responce.statusCode);

        responce.on("data", function (data) {
            const weatherData = JSON.parse(data);
            const temp = weatherData.main.temp;
            const disc = weatherData.weather[0].description;
            const icon = weatherData.weather[0].icon;
            const imgurl = "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/"+ icon +"@2x.png";
            console.log(imgurl);
            console.log(temp);
            console.log(disc);
            res.write("<h1>The weather is " + disc +"</h1>")
            res.write("<h1>The current temperature in London is " + temp + " degree celsius</h1><br>");
            // when i am passing imgurl in img tag i dont get image
            res.write("<img src='imgurl'>");
            res.send();

        });

    });

});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("port started at 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

u are not passing the image url into the url field properly

try:

`` res.write(`<img src = ${imgurl}>`) ``

notice it is ` not '